# check if a class is defined in TCL OO, not using catch

Tags: class, tcl, catch-block

I have a code, and I want to make sure that a class definion is indeed loaded.
Lets say that the class name is foo. I can do the following:
`if { [ catch { foo new } ] } { source "path_to_code" }` 
Is there a way to do it without catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `info` command:

```
if {![info object isa class foo]} {source "path_to_code"}
```

Comment: You can also use `info object isa object` to check if an arbitrary thing is an object.